# "Ave Maria, jungfräuliche Zier"

Tags: translation

My dictionary gives "decoration, ornament" as the translation for *Zier*.  This is clearly unsuitable for translating:

> Ave Maria, jungfräuliche Zier

...the title of a song by Franz Biebl.

> Hail Mary, virgin beauty

...seems also off to me somehow, though maybe that's the best one can do.

Is there a better translation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You shouldn't take poems or lyrics of songs verbatim.**

In middle high German, »zier« was a synonym for »Schönheit« (*beauty*), but this did not mean only visible beauty, but also a beautiful mind, i.e. someone who is of an undoubted character.

Maybe Franz Biebl wanted to refer to this old meaning in his lyrics. But maybe he just set new music to the old lyrics of an old folk song who's lyrics you can red here: http://www.volksmusik-archiv.de/vma/node/2969 (I don't know the lyrics of Biebl's song.) This folk song was published in 1884 (i.e. before Biebl was born) and seems to be even much older.

This old folk song starts with the archangel Gabriel singing to Maria:

> Gegrüßt seist, Maria, jungfräuliche Zier!
>   Du bist voll der Gnaden, der Herr ist mit dir.
>   Ein ganz neue Botschaft,
>   ein unerhörts Ding
>   von der himmlischen Hofstatt
>   ich, Gabriel, bring.

Note, that »Zier« in line 1 rhymes to »dir« in line 2, and line 2 is an almost verbatim quote out of the German version of »Ave Maria«. This 500 years old prayer starts with the words:

> Gegrüßet seist du Maria, **voll der Gnade, der Herr ist mit dir**, ...

I think that the part »jungfräuliche Zier« mainly was inserted into the folk song to have a rhyme to »der Herr ist mit dir«.

This is my attempt to translate these lyrics:

> Hail Mary, virgin beauty!
>   You are full of grace, our lord is with thee.
>   A very new message,
>   an outrageous thing
>   from the heavenly farmstead
>   I, Gabriel, bring.